# Sqlite memory leak. Bad tutorial or it's usage?

Tags: android, sqlite, memory-leaks, sqliteopenhelper

I am trying to build my first app which, but struggling with sqlite.

I get this

```
W/SQLiteConnectionPool﹕ A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/data/com.example.user.myApp/databases/testJavaNorm.sqlite' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
W/SQLiteConnectionPool﹕ A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/data/com.example.user.myApp/databases/testJavaNorm.sqlite' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
W/SQLiteConnectionPool﹕ A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/data/com.example.user.myApp/databases/testJavaNorm.sqlite' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
```

As a beginner I used [Sqlite tutorial](http://blog.char95.com/importing-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/). As I understand I have to write public methods in the end of DB class and call it like was shown in 3.

But Android studio sometimes show a memory leak.

I noticed that there isn't any db.close anywhere. So I added it in call methods, later public methods. Still have leaks. Now I have read that cursor also have to be closed.

Am I using this tutorial wrong? Or it's a bad tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I using this tutorial wrong? Or it's a bad tutorial?

It is a very bad tutorial. In addition to the bugs that you pointed out, it hard-codes filesystem paths. **NEVER HARD-CODE FILESYSTEM PATHS**. It also completely breaks the `SQLiteOpenHelper` model.

For the specific case of wanting to package a database with your app, please [use `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper).

Answer (score 0):

It's finally the tutorial you have used. There have to be an `cursor.close();` after the `if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {....}`

Still:
I think there are better tutorials available. Some things in this tutorial doesn't make sense, like the `cursor.moveToFirst()` around the while loop. [I would do this on this way.](https://gist.github.com/Smove/f4f412cc776f66fb3050)